# c# HTTPWebRequest POST to Objective-c NSMutableURLRequest statusCode 405

Tags: objective-c, post, nsmutableurlrequest

What is nice and simple in C# is turning out to be a bear in Objective C

```
        static private void AddUser(string Username, string Password)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://192.168.1.10:8080/DebugUser?userName=" + Username + "&password=" + Password));

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = 0;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.Write(response.StatusCode);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

works fine, but when I try and convert it to Objective-C (IOS), all I get is "Connection State 405 Method not allowed"

```
-(void)try10{
    NSLog(@"Web request started");
    NSString *user = @"me@inc.com";
    NSString *pwd = @"myEazyPassword";
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",user,pwd];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSLog(@"Post Data: %@", post);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.10:8080"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(theConnection){
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"connection initiated");
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers to using POST on IOS would be a great help.

Comment: userName in C#, username in objC. Is it ok to have lowercase n in objC?

Comment: Also, your objC code contains no reference to DebugUser , your posting to /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those requests are not exactly the same.
C# example sends POST request to `/DebugUser` with query params `?userName=<username>&password=<password>`, obj-c one sends POST request to `/` with form-urlencoded data `userName=<username>&password=<password>`. I guess that problem is this small mistake in URI path (mostly those small, stupid mistakes takes more time to solve than real problems.. ;) ). Additionally I would suggest to url encode params, in this example your username `me@inc.com` should be encoded as `me%40inc.com` to be valid url/form-url encoded data. See also my code-comment about ivar.

Something like that should work (written on the fly, I haven't compile that / check before posting):

```
-(void)try10{
    NSString *user = @"me%40inc.com";
    NSString *pwd = @"myEazyPassword";
    NSString *myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.1.10:8080/DebugUser?username=%@&password=%@",user,pwd];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(theConnection){
        // I suppose this one is ivar, its safer to use @property
        // unless you want to implement some custom setters / getters
        //webData = [NSMutableData data];
        self.webData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"connection initiated");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I tried at least 10 different methods with that same little mistake in it all day!  Some of the methods I tried were huge.  this is nice and simple and works.